# Flag inside OnClickListener defaults to 0 even though initialized to 1?

Tags: java, android, button, listener, onclicklistener

I'm trying to make a two-player Tic-Tac-Toe app, and it requires two separate things to happen on the same buttons `(b[][])`, either turn the text `""` to an `"O"`, or an `"X"`, depending on whose turn it is.

Here, I have a flag defaulted to 1, which should signal that it's player 1 (O's) turn. Running the program, it's always player 2 (X's) turn no matter what.

I'm a little confused as to how `onClickListener` works. I can see that perhaps the conditional `flag == 1` is being called straight away, immediately setting the flag to 0? It still does not make sense to me that it does not go through the process of setting button text to `"O"` first though. What is happening? How do I go about fixing this?

```
class MyClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
            int x;
            int y;


            public MyClickListener(int x, int y) {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
            }


            public void onClick(View view) {

                int flag = 1;

                if (b[x][y].isEnabled()) {
                    b[x][y].setEnabled(false);
                }
                    if(flag == 1) {
                        b[x][y].setText("O");
                        c[x][y] = 0;
                        textView.setText("player 1's turn");
                        checkBoard();
                        flag = 0;

                    }
                    if(flag == 0){
                        b[x][y].setText("X");
                        c[x][y] = 1;
                        textView.setText("player 2's turn");
                        checkBoard();
                        flag = 1;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: you are initializing flag to be 1 at the start.

Comment: @Untitled123 Yes, I know, but the program behaves as though I had initialised it to 0. It is only going through the second conditional, where flag is 0.

Comment: you need an else if flag==0, since it is set to 0 in the first if and then goes into the 2nd if.

Comment: @Untitled123 Well actually, I now see that this was just a small oversight, and wasn't the real problem. I had expected the flags to switch, considering that what i tried to do at the end of the conditionals. That's the part that is confusing me. Sorry. I'll edit the question a bit.

Comment: I would guess that initializing flag inside this function is not what you want. Consider putting that flag init in a constructor.

Comment: @Untitled123 Thank you, that did it!

Answer (score 0):

replace the

```
if(flag == 0)
```

with

```
else if(flag == 0)
```

This will make it skip over the second if statement after setting flag to 0.

```
class MyClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        int x;
        int y;
        int flag;

        public MyClickListener(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            flag = 1;
        }


        public void onClick(View view) {



            if (b[x][y].isEnabled()) {
                b[x][y].setEnabled(false);

                if(flag == 1) {
                    b[x][y].setText("O");
                    c[x][y] = 0;
                    textView.setText("player 1's turn");
                    checkBoard();
                    flag = 0;

                }
                else if(flag == 0){
                    b[x][y].setText("X");
                    c[x][y] = 1;
                    textView.setText("player 2's turn");
                    checkBoard();
                    flag = 1;
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that has the thing start with p1, thank you. It still does not work as intended, though, the flag doesn't switch either which way still... I suppose that's another thing to look into. Any ideas?

Comment: What people have mentioned already is the way to go. You want to initialize that flag outside of that method, probably within the constructor. So under your variables x and y, have int flag, then procede to initialize inside the constructor flag = 1. Remove the int flag = 1 inside the onClick method. That should help fix some  things